# load GTZAN dataset in python using tensorflow,keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

hi im using keras in python and im new in machine learning
i want to load the data , i have a folder that in this folder i have sub-folders
and in the sub folders i have spectograma of audio files
example:

(i have 10 sub folders each sub folders is genre and inside the sub folders i have 100 audio files spectograma (jpg)  that connect to the genre)

data->

```
   pop-> 1.jpg
         2.jpg
         ....
   
  hip hop-> 1.jpg
         2.jpg
         ....
   
  blues-> 1.jpg
         2.jpg
         ....
```

how can i load the data and split ?

(try, (x_train,y_train) , (x_test,y_test) = ????)

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

Answer (score 0):

From tensorflow guide [tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images](https://tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images):

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Get validation

```
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

To get label

```
train_ds.class_names
```